# Do CSS transformed elements have default z-index?

Tags: css, z-index, css-transforms

I've a pretty basic example here, am having a fixed header with other elements which are stacked one after another, single element is transformed using `transform: rotate(360deg)`.

So only the transformed element is getting over the fixed bar when the page is scrolled, where other elements doesn't. So the question is do transformed elements have default `z-index`?

> When you use `z-index: -1;` for `.transform_me` it behaves normal

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qM4r2/)

CSS

```
.fixed {
    height: 30px;
    background: #f00;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.transform_me {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}

span {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
}
```

> Note: It will be solved if we use say `z-index: 999;` for the fixed
>   div, but that's not what am looking for.

Comment: Any positive value for `z-index` including **1** will fix it, but as you said it seems like it gets its own layer, but it is less than `z-index:1` ? +1

Comment: @JEES I don't know, this is funny, I mean what if I have numerous transformed elements, I've to change `z-index` for each, I want to know why this happens

Comment: It'd be a big mess, in [This Link](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-transitions-and-2d-transforms/#transforms) from opera it says -*Note that a transform doesn't affect the flow of the document, so if the element is moved to where another element is already positioned it will overlap that element rather than the content flowing around or under it. Elements later in the document also will not take up the space vacated by the transformed element*-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, any value other than `none` for the `transform` results in **the creation of both a stacking context and a containing block**. The object acts as a containing block for fixed positioned descendants.

From the [specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#transform-rendering).

[**Stacking context**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context).

Comment: Should I use `z-index: -1;` for all transformed elements?

Comment: I'd just give `.fixed` a positive `z-index`.