# CSS Transform/Rotate causing higher z-index than fixed element

Tags: css, z-index, transform, css-position

When applying `transform: rotate(-90deg);` to an element, this is causing a higher `z-index` than other elements which are in a fixed position.

I've created a jsFiddle to easily demonstrate the differences between two divs which are identical, apart from one has transforms applied to it:

http://jsfiddle.net/GzURY/1/

Previously I thought there would be no differences to an element if it had a transform style applied to it, other than it would appear rotated etc.

Why is this happening?

Comment: see the answer by Ana Tudor here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433864/do-css-transformed-elements-have-default-z-index. Anyway you may solve with position: relative and z-index: -1 for .rotate